# Facebook Requests ID(s) retrieve and delete

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

So I'm developing a small web app, that implements the `Requests Dialog(User-to-User)`.

I'm able to send an invite and also successfully to save data as request id and user id. But when the user gets redirected to my app, after clicking on the request, i can't retrieve request id as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting and then delete it.

But i see the request id in the address bar of the browser and it looks like this: http://apps.facebook.com/myownapp/?fb_source=request&request_ids=210655195715938 and REQUEST_URI is: /halten/?fb_source=request&request_ids=210655195715938

i tried with javascript:

```
function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
    FB.api('', {
        "ids": requestIds
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}​
```

or with php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    $requestIDs = explode(',' , $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
    foreach($requestIDs as $requestID) {
      try {
        $delete_success = $facebook->api('/' . $requestID, 'DELETE');
      } catch(FacebookAPIException $e) {
        error_log($e);
      }
    }
```

but the request_ids is always empty but my browser shows the request_id

So the question is how to handle the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please tell me if it is possible to set a redirecturl using javascript api

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/";
//–>
</script>
as a defualt but google javascript redirect url and you'll get the picture :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `User to User Request` is actually notified to the user in 4 levels.

1) Jewel notification

[image]

2) Bookmarks counter

[image]

3) Right top counter

[image]

4) Weird location notification inside the app(I did not know what this was called sorry)

[image]

All of these request will take the user to the app but unfortunately on the Jewel notification(#1) request url will contain `all` the request IDs and the remaining will contain only a single request ID.

Say you send 4 requests `(1,2,3,4)`

`#1` in url will have `1&2&3&4`

`#2,#3,#4` will have `one of those` depending on which notification you response to

Hope this makes sense and answers the question.

Comment: hm so it is better when my app uses app-to-user request. it 'll be a small game after all, because i clearly need a unique url or something that i can depend on. the problem is app-to-user request doesn't send jewel notification, it counts up only the bookmark counter, right?

Comment: app-to-user request is similar to #3, in fact the notification below the red tick is a app-user notification

Comment: It is no longer possible to retrieve the REQUEST_IDS using $_GET. Any ideas for other solutions?

Comment: @Mattias: Let me check please