# FB Canvas app: Get request id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

A user has sent a app request (using the native fb.ui:apprequest). When his friend opens the notification ("xxx has invited you to APP") the URL looks like this:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/app_name/?fb_source=notification&
  request_ids=THE_REQUEST_ID&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&
  notif_t=app_request
```

On this page, my webpage is shown inside an iframe.

Previously, I could simply call: `$_GET['request_ids']` on my page (inside the iframe) to get the request_id *(why? because I need to track who sent the invite)*.

However, this no longer works. I have tried pretty much everything.

According to facebook docs, the previous solution I made use of was the correct one. See:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests#deleting *(scroll a bit down, to the PHP example)*

Have Facebook removed this feature? That would be sad, and I guess/hope not!

People have had similar questions (all suggest the solution, which no longer works):

- [Get request_ids in a canvas app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698163/get-request-ids-in-a-canvas-app)
- [Facebook Requests ID(s) retrieve and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226640/facebook-requests-ids-retrieve-and-delete?rq=1)
- [Retrieve User ID of Facebook App Invitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839527/retrieve-user-id-of-facebook-app-invitor?rq=1)

Is the only solution really to pass the inviters user_id? (as suggested in [Retrieve User ID of Facebook App Invitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839527/retrieve-user-id-of-facebook-app-invitor?rq=1)). And if so, can I then retrieve it, when the user clicks on the notification?

EDIT:

I have also tried to use: `exit(print_r($facebook->getSignedRequest(), TRUE));` - which outputs:

```
algorithm => HMAC-SHA256
issued_at => 1395696960
user =>
    country => dk
    locale => da_DK
    age =>
        min => 21
user_id => the_user_id (ONLY WHEN APP HAS ALREADY BEEN AUTHED IT SEEMS)
```

Close, but no cigar.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it, and I am not aware of any announcement regarding a change in that. However, Facebook is in the process of rolling out a new “layout” for pages (nothing too dramatic, but quite a bit of minor changes), and I have already seen people complaining about a similar issue with page tab apps and the `app_data` parameter not being passed correctly any more … so my guess is, they might have botched something up in that process. I’d suggest opening a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/trending/

Comment: Thanks. I have filled a bugreport!

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to this for quite a while, and the best I could get is to make an API call to `/me/apprequests` - it will return all the requests from the app.

I know you still can't figure out which one you've clicked (in case you received multiple invites), but it's a step ahead until FB sorts its things...

Simple JS example:

```
FB.api('/me/apprequests', function(r){
    if (r && r.data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < r.data.length; i++) {
            var id = r.data[i].id.split('_')[0]; // this is the request id
            console.log(id, r.data[i]);
        };
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. But the problem is not on the facebook side. It is actually an configuration problem on our Nginx server.

We had a redirect set up on the root page and it removes all cgi params that facebook passes to the canvas app. After fixing the Nginx config, everything works as expected.